# Is raising NSInternalInconsistencyException guaranteed to crash by default?

Tags: ios, objective-c, assert, nsassert

I use `NSAssert` to detect unrecoverable conditions in my code. I enabled assertions in release mode as well because if an assertion fails in my code, it's guaranteed to be unrecoverable.

`NSAssert` raises `NSInternalInconsistencyException` and I've read conflicting posts about `NSInternalInconsistencyException` being caught by some frameworks and thus not crashing the app. Is this correct? I want my app to crash any time an `NSAssert` fails.

Will it also crash if thrown on background threads such as from a dispatch queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my understanding (backed by experience) that NO exceptions are guaranteed to cause a crash. The system frequently catches them.

Comment: I create a block local variable, don't initialize it to anything, and then invoke it.

Comment: Note that Apple takes a dim view of apps that crash themselves, and will probably reject you. You're supposed to display a message to the user about the problem and NOT crash/exit.

Comment: That would be a recoverable error and handled appropriately. Assertions would be for programming errors that will result in undefined behaviour such as `nil` pointer arguments. The app would never crash in production unless such an error slipped through testing, in which case a crash is preferable to silent data corruption.